# I cannot print text on the screen with the command " Macd Line == Signal Line " . How can I do it?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading, strategy-pattern, indicator

I cannot print text on the screen with the command " Macd Line == Signal Line " . How can I do it ?

I am using these codes. It's actually very simple, but I couldn't transfer it to the screen.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='macd esit', overlay=true)    

[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)    
alarm = (signalLine == macdLine)    
plotshape(alarm, style=shape.triangledown, text='ALARM', color=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.belowbar, size=size.small)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Comparing two float variables with `==` is a bad idea. Those values are not the same. What you are seeing is their numbers rounded to four decimal places. However, if you increase your precision to 8, you will see that they are actually different.

[image]

As a workaround, you can use the `ta.cross()` function. This will let you know that they have crossed each other. Or you can use an estimation method. Find the delta between two and check if it is less than x%.

Answer (score 0):

*signalLine* and *macdLine* will rarely have the same value. But they cross

Try with [ta.cross](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dcross)
something like that:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='macd esit', overlay=true)    

[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)    
alarm = ta.cross (signalLine, macdLine)
plotshape(alarm, style=shape.triangledown, text='ALARM', color=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.belowbar, size=size.small)
```